# react - × TypeError: users.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to do a get in my api that returns only one user, that in this user will have one of the tasks related to the user. This is an example of my interface.

```
interface IUsers {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  tasks: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    priority: string;
    name_project: string;
    date: Date;
  };
```

example of the code, in which I am trying to search for users, in the console.log it is shown that the user is returning me, but to render on the screen, the error occurs that .map is not a function

```
  const { user, signOut } = useAuth();

  const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUsers[]>([]);

  const getUser = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await api.get(`/users/${user.id}`);
    console.log(response.data);
    setUsers(response.data);
  }, [user.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, [getUser]);
```

And this is the way I’m trying to render the information on the screen.

```
<Container>
      {users.map((users) => (
        <Main key={users.id}>
....
```

result from console.log

```
{id: "9f389cd1-4c1d-4fe9-840a-2a513984aea6", name: "Wesley Israel", email: "wesleyteste@gmail.com", password: "$2a$08$PrV.UZ9LXe0IMQQZ0qw6ruNt28mj7rcOIUtxt1S1PQiOjjR03qA46", created_at: "2021-04-27T11:49:09.510Z", …}
created_at: "2021-04-27T11:49:09.510Z"
email: "wesleyteste@gmail.com"
id: "9f389cd1-4c1d-4fe9-840a-2a513984aea6"
name: "Wesley Israel"
password: "$2a$08$PrV.UZ9LXe0IMQQZ0qw6ruNt28mj7rcOIUtxt1S1PQiOjjR03qA46"
tasks: Array(1)
0: {id: "1ee527f1-dc28-4de2-a7dc-050505db034c", title: "Estudar Typescript", name_project: "University", user_id: "9f389cd1-4c1d-4fe9-840a-2a513984aea6", status: "NEW", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
updated_at: "2021-04-27T11:49:09.510Z"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Your response.data is printing an object based on what you post so your state is changing from an array to an object after the api call is done. map won't work unless your data structure is an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help

```js
{users &&(users.map((users) => (
        <Main key={users.id}>
...
)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The map method works with an array. Here your data is an object so it won't have a map method. Please enclose your object in an array. You need to send an array of objects from the backend. Or else in the frontend you need to enclose the response. data in an array. Like **setUser([response.data])**. But it would be good if you get an array of objects from the backend. And if this problem occurs if you have only a single entry of user you can always check if the data is an array or object using **Array.isArray(object)** and if it's an object encloses it in array